# Is there any way to retrieve more accurate MySQL error messages?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near [random snippet of query code]
```

I am very rarely able to deduce something of value from MySQL errors like that one, is there any way to get some more specific data?

I've seen people dismiss this question saying that it's impossible to get exact error data because of how MySQL's syntax works. Is that really so?

Comment: It's accurate enough. "random snippet of query code" isn't actually random but a place where the query isn't syntactically correct. "to get exact error data because of how MySQL's syntax works. Is that really so?" --- it's exact already.

Comment: The error message is normally pretty good because the **near ...** indicates the exact position where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to break down your query into several lines instead of just one long one. This will still show you only the approximate position of your error, but it might help a bit.

Comment: The error message is always 1 line string. It cuts off the newline characters from the original query. So I would say "It always help to **read** the error message", nothing else is necessary.

Comment: Yeah I see the error string is always the same, but when doing line breaks it will tell you the line number where the error occurs, instead of always "line 1", just tried it in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Breaking up the sql query helps, doing it in this helpful online tool will highlight the line specifically - narrowing it down more - hope it helps someone, it helped me => https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/

Answer (score 3):

It's not only MySQL that gives syntax errors like that, MS SQL Server gives very similar messages.

The error message is very accurate in the sense that the code shown in the error message is the exact position where the parser determined that it could no longer go on with parsing the query.

However, the actual error in the query is often somewhat earlier in the query. If you for example misspelled "from" in a query as "fom", the parser will go on thinking that "fom" is an alias for the last field that came before that, and give you a syntax error when it finds a table name instead of the expected comma or "from" keyword. It will point to the table name as the position of the error instead of the misspelled keyword.